# How to create PostBuild event to update javascript version

Tags: .net, jenkins, tfs, msbuild, post-build

I need to create a PostBuild event in my proj file so that after each build, the version of my javascript files get automatically updated based on the build number. Of course, this need to happen only when my js files is modified.

Example: 
1st build: site.js?v=1.2.3
2nd build: site.js?v=1.2.4

Comment: Exactly where is this being updated?

Comment: @stuartd what do you mean?

Comment: @NimaEslamloo, is the javascript file checked into TFS version control? And is the build run during the TFS build process?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT yes all the javascript files are checked into TFS and there's Jenkins which builds the solution every half an hour.